# About Firestore is there some flag I can check if the data is on/off line data?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I [read](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) when on Android in offline mode the `onComplete()` method will never return unless the device goes online so data can be persisted to the backen at Firestore.

When I'm in offline mode and do this `get()` I notice that it return with what I think must be local data since I have the `setPersistenceEnabled(true)`

```
  query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
      @Override
      public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

       }
  });
```

I just have to ask if this is correct? If so is there some flag I can check if the data is online/offline data?

Sometimes doing this `get()` it does not return just hangs there forever, maybe that has to do with my device getting warm after heavy debugging.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unlike in Firebase Realtime database where to enable offline persistence you should have used first, the following line of code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

In Cloud Firestore, for Android and iOS, offline persistence is enabled by default. So, there is no need to use: `setPersistenceEnabled(true)`.

When you are offline and you are using a `get()` call, the result will be from the cached copy of the Cloud Firestore data that your app is actively using.

To check if the data is from cache or from Firestore servers, you can use the following line of code:

```
String source = querySnapshot.getMetadata().isFromCache() ? "Local Cache" : "Firebase Server";
```